# Sorting in Linq-To-Sql by list of indexes

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I implemented a search engine in my website that uses `Linq-To-Sql`. The output of the engine is a list of `Result`.
To increase security and performance, I've added a `CachedResult` table to my database. It had these columns:
`ID`, `Date`, `Output`
Where `Output` is a string which represents a list of `integers` which are the `ID`s for another table.
Using the `Where` method, I was able to extract those elements from the database. The problem is that their order is based on their order in the table, not the order of the `integers` in my string.
Therefore, I've added the `OrderBy` method this way:
`db.Uploads.Where(upl => W.Contains(upl.UploadID)).OrderBy(pp => W.IndexOf(pp.UploadID));`
`W` here is a list of `integers` (extracted from the database).
The probelm is that it throws an exception saying that the `Linq-To-Sql translator` cannot translate the `List.IndexOf` method to the appropriate SQL query.

I would like to know if I'm doing this right and there is a solution, or maybe I'm totally wrong and I must seek another way? (i.e making another table that has a relationship with `CachedResults`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can realise the result as a list before sorting, so that it uses Linq-To-Objects instead of Linq-To-Sql for the sorting:

```
db.Uploads
  .Where(upl => W.Contains(upl.UploadID))
  .ToList()
  .OrderBy(pp => W.IndexOf(pp.UploadID));
```

However, that's not very efficient. As the `IndexOf` method is an O(n) operation, the sorting will be an O(n<sup>2</sup>) operation.

Antother solution is to add another table `CachedResultItems` for the integers for each cached result, containing fields like:

```
ID       int
Ouptut   int
Position int
```

Instead of storing a string like `5,7,12,26,81` in the `CachedResult` table, you would have these records in the `CachedResultItems` table (for the ID 42 in the `CachedResult` table):

```
ID   Output  Position
---- ------- ---------
42   5       1
42   7       2
42   12      3
42   26      4
42   81      5
```

Then you can join the two tables, and sort the result on `Position`.

This would also be faster than first getting one result, splitting the string to a list, and use that list in a query, as it's a single query, and it can use indexes more efficiently.